# How do we align the output generated by IAR Embedded Workbench to 4 bytes (or any other desired value)?

Tags: linker, alignment, memory-alignment, iar

IAR Embedded workbench is generating the Output file (`*.txt` as I have selected TI-TXT format). The content of this `.txt` file is as-

```
@mem_address
00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00 11
01 02 03 04 05
```

I want that at the last, the output is aligned to 4 bytes, after which the file would like-

```
@mem_address
00 11 22 33 44 55 66 77 88 99 00 11
01 02 03 04 05 dd dd dd
```

where `dd` can be any dummy valid HEX value.

Is it possible to get the output aligned in IAR?

I have tried using `#pragma data_alignment = 4` but it can only align the variables and has to be written before any variable declaration. Is there any way (possibly by modifying the linker file) such that the whole output gets word-aligned?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ielftool` to fill any gaps in the output file or add some padding at the end. For your use case the following command should work (have a look [IAR C/C++ Development Guide](https://wwwfiles.iar.com/arm/webic/doc/EWARM_DevelopmentGuide.ENU.pdf) for details):

```
ielftool my_input.out my_output.out --fill 0xFF;0–0x14
```

Instead of using the command line you can also configure such operation inside the IAR Workbench. Have a look at the dialog `Project > Options > Linker > Checksum` (see the [IDE Project Management and Building Guide](https://wwwfiles.iar.com/arm/webic/doc/EWARM_IDEGuide.ENU.pdf)).